# Doctrine entity relation not updating

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

Im trying to update a many-to-one relation object of an entity.

This is the code i am using:

```
$em    = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
$user    = $this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();

# find thread
$thread = $em->getRepository('MyBundle:Thread')->findThreadById($threadid);

# find thread posts
$query = $em->getRepository('MyBundle:Post')->findThreadPosts($thread->getId());

# create form
$form = $this->createForm(new PostType(), new Post($user, $thread));

# handle form
$form->handleRequest($request);
if ($form->isValid()) {

    $post = $form->getData();
    $em->persist($post);
    $em->flush();
    $logger->debug("POST CREATED with id: " . $post->getId());

    $thread->setLastPost($post);
    $thread->addPostCount(1);
    $thread->setLastPostCreator($user);
    $em->flush();


    $logger->debug("ADDED LAST POST TO thread with id: " . $thread->getId());

    $forum = $thread->getForum();
    $forum->setLastPostCreator($user);
    $forum->addPostCount(1);
    $forum->setLastPostCreator($user);
    $forum->setLastPost($post);
    $em->flush();

    $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add(
        'notice',
        'Your post has been added!'
    );
}

$data['posts']  = $posts;
$data['thread'] = $thread;
$data['form']   = $form->createView();
```

Mapping Post:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<doctrine-mapping xmlns="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping.xsd">
  <entity name="MyBundle\Entity\Post" table="post">

    <id name="id" type="integer" column="id">
      <generator strategy="IDENTITY"/>
    </id>
    <field name="text" type="text" column="text" nullable="false"/>

    <many-to-one field="thread" target-entity="Thread" inversed-by="posts">
      <join-columns>
          <join-column name="thread_id" referenced-column-name="id"/>
      </join-columns>
    </many-to-one>

  </entity>
</doctrine-mapping>
```

Mapping Thread:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<doctrine-mapping xmlns="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping.xsd">
  <entity name="MyBundle\Entity\Thread" table="thread">
    <id name="id" type="integer" column="id">
      <generator strategy="IDENTITY"/>
    </id>

    <field name="postCount" type="integer" column="post_count" nullable="false"/>

    <one-to-one field="lastPost" target-entity="Post">
       <join-column name="last_post_id" referenced-column-name="id"/>
    </one-to-one>

    <one-to-many field="posts" target-entity="Post" mapped-by="thread" />

  </entity>
</doctrine-mapping>
```

**Entity: Thread setter**

```
public function setLastPost(Post $lastPost)
{
    $this->lastPost = $lastPost;
}

public function getLastPost()
{
    return $this->lastPost;
}
```

So whenever i add a post, i will update its parent (the thread). So the thread has the latest post as a many-to-one reference. i also update the count just as a matter of caching and reducing joins.

the count is indeed incremented correctly. However the latest-post reference is not update. When i view my debug logs i also see that there is no query executed for this.

any ideas/thoughts on this? my best guess was that it's not detecting the changes but i have no idea on how to invalidate this kind of data.

Comment: We need to see the mappings for Post and Thread.

Comment: Updated  my original post with mappings

Comment: Is `Thread::lastPost` set never? Or is it not able to be changed after the first time when the association are set? Can you add also the action with the `Thread` creating?

Comment: It's being set but it's just not being persisted to the databank

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the problem is you are setting up and persisting the "inverse side" of the relationship. The docs say:

> Doctrine will only check the owning side of an association for changes.

and

> ManyToOne is always the owning side of a bidirectional association.

So in your case, you have a manyToOne bidirectional relationship between a thread and lastPosts, where the lastPost entity is the "owning side"(manyToOne side) and the thread is the "inverse side". I believe that you should have a setThread() function on your Post entity, and if after handling the form you run $post->setThread($thread) and then persist($post) things will work out.

Also, IMO, it seems like you should just have a relationship between thread->posts, and use a custom repository function, or find and sort by the createdAt date (assuming it exists) to obtain the "last post". The Many Threads to One Last Post relationship doesn't seem right to me, shouldn't a thread only have one "last post" (aka oneToOne relationship)?

Comment: The last post is a heavy query, its also frequently updated on a busy forum. thats why i decided to have a caching field (which is normally never used in an RDBMS) Please correct me if i'm wrong. I'm testing your solution now.

Comment: Yes that's correct it should be a one-to-one. adjusting now and will update if working asap

Comment: That makes sense. I added a note about the thread->lastPost relationship. If it is a oneToOne relationship, I think the way you have your controller configured will work, because the docs say that in a oneToOne the side with the foreign key is the owning side (the thread in your case).

Comment: Changed to a one-to-one, still doctrine seems to not detect changes

Comment: Is is accurate to say that your post is getting created succesfully with an id, but that the last_post_id field for your thread is null?

Comment: Yes that's correct. The post is created and persisted succesfully, but the lastPost is not being set (verified this with debug logs)

Comment: Only thing that looks kind of off is the <join-columns> tag on the oneToOne relationship. Should just be <join-column> I believe. I'd fix that, clear the cache, validate the schema, and then see what happens.

Comment: Changed that, validated schema, cleared cache, restarted webserver/database but it's still not detecting changes.

Comment: I took your code and tested it in my project and it seems to work OK. It wasn't setting the thread_id in the controller, so I had to add a post->setThread after form handling. But the last_post_id is getting set correctly. The code I used for testing is here: http://pastebin.com/WVKH09ZG . Noticed your namespace is 'MyBundle/Entity' where I had to do 'test/MyBundle/Entity' but assuming that is just how your directories are structured. Out of ideas I guess, good luck with  the resolution.

Comment: Thank you you certainly helped me well

Comment: Okay, i changed lastPostCreator to a manyToOne again (which is logical). then i changed the ordening of my setters. first i did addPostCount(1); $em->flush(); after that i do the lastPostCreator() and the lastPost() and flush and everything seems to work all of a sudden.

Answer (score 0):

does your $thread->setLastPost($post) method look like this:

```
public function setLastPost(Post $post)
{
    $this->lastPost = $post;
}
```

Does it get called? Whats happening when you insert an debug statement?

Have you set by_reference right, if its needed?

```
"So, all that by_reference=false really does is force the framework to call the setter on the parent object."
```

http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html#by-reference

If the above advises dont work, could you pls provide more information like the FormTypes and the relevant entity setters and getters?!

Comment: Hello, thank you for your reply. The setLastPost function is called, and looks like the setter you posted. by_reference is not needed since i fetch the thread. I updated my original post with more detailed code. I dont think FormTypes are relevant in this case. i also added my entities

Comment: Whats happening when you do this:
public function setLastPost(Post $post)
{
    $this->lastPost = $post;
    $post->setThread($this);
}

Comment: Doesn't change anything, the post already has the association with thread. as defined here: `new Post($user, $thread)`

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this. The solution that worked for me was to call `$em->merge($entity);` on each of the entities on the "many" side followed by `$em->flush();`.